# Is clouding of lime added water a sign of spoilage?

Tags: food-safety

I squeezed half an Indian (asian country, India) lime in a 1 litre glass bottle in the evening. Next day morning, its got a bit cloudish, even the smell & taste has changed.

What happened, is the water spoiled?

Answer (score 2):

pectin and other molecules are in the fresh juice.  they clump and cloud the liquid.  it's normal

refrigerated, up to a few days, as long as it smells good, it is good.

that ratio of juice to water just won't give bad microbes enough to work with to hurt you badly

if you don't like the smell or taste, toss it!

there's good information on how to clarify fruit juices here https://www.foodandwine.com/fwx/drop-your-muddler-heres-how-and-why-clarify-your-fruit-juice